# Shebang option ' #!/bin/csh -f '

Tags: linux, shell, csh, shebang

What does the Shebang option -f do? How do I find, or man, detailed explanations on all Shebang options?

```
#! /bin/csh -f
```

Comment: It's not a shebang option, but rather a `-f` flag to the csh shell. Check `man csh` and you'll find that the option ignores user rc files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't any "shebang options".

Any options there are options to the binary in the shebang.

So that's a `csh` option.

Specifically (from [the man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/csh.1)):

> **-f**
>
> The shell will start faster, because it will neither search for nor execute commands from the file .cshrc in the invoker's home directory. Note: if the environment variable HOME is not set, fast startup is the default.